# ASP.NET, two Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config

I have a .NET application with all the aspx pages and the main web.config in the root folder but I now have a situation where I need a portal like section for other users. I have created a new folder with it's own unique aspx pages and a second web.config.

I especially need a second web.config to have the `<authentication>` with a `<forms loginUrl="" defaultUrl=">` for this portal section and a `<authentication>` too.

I have implemeted this second web.config in the way I created the first and I am getting this error message:

```
    It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefintion='MachineToApplication' 
    beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being 
    configured as an application in IIS.
```

Now I think the main web.config file is conflicting with the this second webconfig in it's folder. I'm not sure how to fix this, I have seen theories on how this works but no solid code.

Thank you for any suggestions and your time, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, create a virtual directory, under your main application. The local web.config will overide stuff in your main web.config, but still use you main web.config for everything else (i.e. ConnectionStrings, encoding, etc.).